Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() on Debian 12.5 with Apache2
I am trying to run my server with php 8.2 but it can't connect to my MariaDB database with mysqli.
I have extension=mysqli in my php.ini
When I do php -m | grep mysqli I get this:
% php -m | grep mysqli
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

